# can we change persistent workflow bookmark?

Tags: c#, workflow, persistent

I have a long running workflow on IIS with persistent bookmarks on SQL server.
Sometimes, I want to restart workflow for an persistent instance. For example, assume a workflow with 2 sequential bookmarks. I start workflow for an entity with instanceId = 'instance01' and it moves to second bookmark. Now, though 'instance01' is waiting for external call of second bookmark but I need to restart workflow for this instance. Can I restart workflow for an instance? Or can I change persistent bookmark for an instanec?